# jquery animate opacity has an impact of other divs? weird behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, opacity

I've got a really strange jquery behavior. I want to make a grid like background with animated tiles (opacity to .8 and back to .25 on mouseover and mouseleave).

As this should be my background it should'n have an impact on my content div.

Unfortunately it doesn't work as expected. THe content div(Which i colored red for testing purposes) gets animated, too.

Here's a [link the the site](http://jsfiddle.net/3XgRA/%20%28updated%20jsfiddle%29).

Comment: Is there any chance you could post a minimum demo, reproducing your problem, on a collaborative site? Such as [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com), perhaps? (It's just a little easier to see what's going on, and work with it, there.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Here you go :) http://jsfiddle.net/3XgRA/

Comment: I'm sorry, but could you explain step-by-step what you *want* to happen? What elements do you want to hover over, to cause what effect?

Comment: Thanks for your efforts and your interest in helping me :) I've commented the answer below...

Answer (score 0):

Part of the problem could be that, when you mouseover the background tiles, the event is bubbling up to the content div. You could try doing this somewhere in your event listeners:

```
e.stopPropagation();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm adjusting your code to use the `.hover()` event instead of juggling mouseover/mouseout, also I'm using fadeTo instead of manually animating opacity.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#page-bg ul li img.keyword').hover(function(){
            $(this).fadeTo('slow',0.8);
        }, 
        function() {
            $(this).fadeTo('slow',0.25);
        });     
    ...
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't help. :-( Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, this doesn't solve your problem, but it's nicer way of doing the same animation...

Comment: Okay, thanks for that, I'll keep that in mind :-) when should one use mouseover, ... then?

Answer (score 0):

The content div is not animated, but the page-bg div is on the top of the content (because of absolute position), so when you change opacity, the content div (in the background) is getting visible...

Comment: So what is the solution at this point? I thought I can achieve the alignment with z-index.

Comment: I'm not sure what your intent is. Z-index will not solve that (if content is on the top - then you will see no animation at all - it's gona be hidden by the content, opposite is what you can see now). Could you explain your intent bit more ? How exactly the result should look like ? You can have "header" with the animation and than "content", something like that: http://jsfiddle.net/qtnNK/

Comment: Sorry for my bad explanation. That's exactly what I want to do. My aim is to set this as a background(repeated down to the bottom, so that I can have some kind of "letter-grid". My content div HAS to hide some area of the background.

Comment: Ok, then, z-index is the sollution... `#pg-bg` should have smaller z-index, so that `#content` is on the top of that...

Comment: but that's the actual problem. Although #pg-bg has a lower z-index ' content gets faded too and looks not like an individual element. http://jsfiddle.net/3XgRA/

Comment: heres an updated version. can't edit my last comment anymore. http://jsfiddle.net/ejQbr/